# Error : Unable to execute dex

Tags: android, eclipse

I get this error when I try to launch my AVD, i search the internet and this forum put nothing works.
Can anybody help me?

```
[2013-04-19 19:09:02 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-04-19 19:09:02 - ScaryFairgroundRideApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

-----Solution to error ----------

I removed the android-support-v4 from my libs folder in my project and everything is working.
Solution from 
@dymmeh

Comment: I'm assuming you have the support library jar in your project and reference another project that also has the support library jar. You can remove the support library from your project if that's the case. You should only have 1 version of a library referenced throughout your project

Comment: @dymmeh thanks that fixed my problem. I removed the android-support-v4 from my libs folder in my project and everything is working.

Comment: @dymmeh I get the same when I updated the support library. I tried removing it from my main project but then I get an error since I don't have it. I use a LocalBroadCast service from the support library so I do reference it from my project, and I'm using ActionBarSherlock that references it on its project.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I removed the android-support-v4 from my libs folder in my project and everything is working. Solution from @dymmeh

Comment: great awnser, my issue was that I had android-support-v4 added from maven, also I had android-support-v13 jar in libs, so i just removed maven dependancy, works perfectly now. thanks!

Comment: I have removed android-support-v4 from build path from maven, right click my project -> Build path -> Configure build path

Comment: I am facing the same error, but unable to remove android-support-v4, because I am using ActionBarDrawerToggle and it has dependency on android-support-v4. How to fix this prob?

Answer (score 5):

Removed android-support-v4 from build path worked for almost..

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the Maven Dependencies, I just removed the dependency tag for Android Support Library from `pom.xml`